# Changing Browser Height Doesn't Change Responsive Image Height

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design

Hi I believe my webpage is written ok to make sure that when the browser window height changes the images size changes, however when adjusting the height only of the browser window the images do not change in width and height in order to be fully visible.

Take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/npa7tbqw/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    background: none;
    color: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.page {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
.page-text {
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.table1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.responsive {
position: relative;
max-width: 90%;
max-height: auto;
}
.container {
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<!-- jquery resize -->
<script>
causeRepaintsOn = $("body, fix, h1, h2, h3");

$(window).resize(function() {
    causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="container">
                <video id="video" preload="auto" poster="http://dummyimage.com/600%20x%20400/17c700/000ed1.jpg" autoplay muted loop>
                </video> 
                <div class="page">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                <table cellpadding="5" class="table1" >
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="width:50%; text-align: left;">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/315%20x%20450/000/fff.jpg" class="responsive"></img>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="width:50%; text-align: right;" >
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/315%20x%20450/000/fff.jpg" class="responsive"></img>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="25%" valign="top" style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</td>
   <td width="25%" ><!-- LEAVE CELL BLANK --></td>
   <td width="25%" ><!-- LEAVE CELL BLANK --></td>
   <td width="25%" valign="top" style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
            </div>
            </div>                  
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

welcome to **SO**. First off I feel that I should point out that *Responsive Websites* change depending on the width of the site, and not the height.

That said, after looking at your JSFiddle, it seems to be working perfectly fine. Websites **SHOULD NOT** adjust depending on the height of the browser, only the width.

Comment: hi michael, thanks for the welcome and the response. i feel that in th example i gave you the captions and the images fall strangely out of the container they are sitting in and can't be seen.

Comment: ...which is slightly problematic, even though "Websites SHOULD NOT adjust depending on the height of the browser, only the width." as you say.

Comment: Responsive web design is about adapting your application to the device used to access it. If that means adapting according to the width or height or both depends on the application.

Answer (score 0):

max-height cannot have a value of `auto`. 

Here are the possible values of max-height: none|*length*|initial|inherit;

I recommend using a simpler example in your fiddle, esp. without tables, so that you can hone in on what's going on with that particular element. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/o145t6rm/

Comment: the height seems to be working well, thanks. how could this be changed in to a "Table" like format where there are two images in parallel as in the example. the other thing was that now with your example doesn't repsond to width change. i will have a go. thanks again.